# Conexion remota a base de Acess utilizando c#

Tags: c#, base-de-datos

Hola tendo que conectar 3 bases de acces que estan en diferentes PC y no estan en la mismas red, las bases son las mismas, lo que necesito es de una 4 Pc conectarme con las 3, de que forma puedo haerlo, espero y me puedan ayuar.

Asi me conecto localmente:

static OleDbConnection conexion = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\mibas.mdb");

Comment: Solo tenes que modificar el datasource para que apunte a las otras bases. como es access, tenes que tener acceso a los archivos.

Comment: `no estan en la mismas red` Vas a tener que ponerlas en la misma red, otra opción que quizás funcione es usar algún programa para compartir archivos tipo Dropbox Google Drive, One Drive y probar.

Comment: Si estan en resdes diferentes, ok gracias, probare.

Comment: Encontre esta forma pero no se como hacerla Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=\\Nombre_Servidor\Directorio_Compartido\Path_Compartido\Tu_BaseDatos.mbd

Comment: Creo que lo anterior funciona en la misma red pero de forma local con distintas pc

Comment: O puedes crear tu propio tunel de red con alguna herramienta. Yo suelo utilizar [Hamachi](https://www.vpn.net). Creo que sería una buena opción. Saludos

Comment: Y que quieres decir cuando afirmas que "las bases son las mismas", significa eso que tienen la misma estructura y gestionan la misma información. Si es así ¿por que tres bases de datos?, ¿No seria mejor una sola base de datos, hospedada en una sola PC a la que tengan acceso las demás PC a trabes de la red?

Comment: Mauricio Contreras como seria eso crear tu propio tunel de red con alguna herramienta

Comment: Si tienen la misma estructura y gestion pero contienen datos diferentes, si seria mas facil si tengo las 3 en una sola pc,pero no es asi